# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie throwing NullReferenceException in async action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.0, async-await

I am finding that `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is throwing a NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object inside an async action on an azure website.

I found the following:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743350/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-throws-nullreferenceexception-if-called-in-an-async-action-in-mvc4

However I already have

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

set and my code works fine locally I only experience the problem when I deploy to azure. I am using Azure Websites (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/), it was my understanding that this uses the web.config normally? I have also tried adding the appsetting through the Azure control panel

[image]

And adding `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to my awaited method but have had no luck.

The following code will throw the exception

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("test", true);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Anyone know how I can get this to work?**

**UPDATE:**

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<GetRethrowWithNoStackLossDelegate>b__1b(Task task) +91
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__3e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +240
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +96
```

**UPDATE**

I found it works if setting the Cookie manually

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "test", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, null, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

I'm not going to answer the question though as would like to know why `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is throwing the exception and why it is behaving differently on Azure Websites

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Are you sure web sites currently support the unreleased ASP.NET 4.5?

Comment: @svick Have added the stack trace

Comment: @StephenCleary Have updated the question tags, it should only be using ASP.NET 4 and the Async Targeting Pack

Comment: I'm pretty sure `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is only supported on ASP.NET 4.5, but I also don't think this is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This issue is not specific to Azure - the method FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie will throw a null reference exception in an async action when an await statement is called before FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie is called.

The easiest solution is to use the following:

```
        Response.Cookies.Add(FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("user-1", true));
```

An alternative would be to specify the ticket creation yourself:

```
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            2,
            "user-1",
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
            true,
            String.Empty,
            "/");

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(".AUTH", encTicket));
```

Comment: Could you provide some source as to why this is the case? I've come across this issue several times, but haven't been able to find backing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At present time, .NET 4.5 is not supported in Windows Azure Web Sites. You will need to downgrade your project to .NET 4.0 which will also mean you will need to rewrite the code to not use async.

You could attempt to bin deploy the .NET 4.5 assemblies that are required by your application

Comment: The application is using .NET 4 with the Async Targeting Pack, I think Stephen Cleary's point that `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is only supported in .NET 4.5 was the reason it was failing on azure and not locally

Answer (score 0):

you can change this way also it up to you

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.google.com"));
    t1.Wait();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("test", true);
    return View();
}
```

this way work for me and i got idea from  GlennMorton 1st answer

thanks.